# Zend Framework 2 Validation require extension

Tags: validation, zend-framework2

When i am using 'Alpha' validator in my application, Zend throws error `(Zend\I18n\Filter component requires the intl PHP extension)`. Installing Extension is not a problem but my shared hosting server does not allow to install any extension. So how can i use validators without installing extensions ?

Comment: I had the same issue and i had the administrator at my work install the extension and it worked like a charm . Without it you can use the classes under Zend\Validator. Cant think of any way to make it work without the extension unless you create your own class and method to check if Alpha with a regexp.

Comment: You mean to sat, there is no chance without installing the extension ?

Comment: Well I only got it to work with the extension. Cant see how you can make it work without it. Unless as i said before create a custom method which does the same.